# Equivalent criteria for a subset $S\subseteq [-N,N)$ to be measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reading Measure Theory from L.F Richardson's "Measure and Integration: A Concise Introduction to Real Analysis". This is a problem which I have not been able to complete.

> Suppose that $S\subseteq[-N,N)$. Show that $S$ is a measurable subset
> of $[-N,N)$ if and only if for each $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an
> open set $G\supseteq S$ and a closed set $F\subseteq S$ such that $\mu
>  (G)-\mu (F)<\varepsilon$.

The author asks to use the following theorem in the solution:

> Let $\mu$ be a finite, countably additive measure, constructed from
> finitely additive measure on a field $\mathfrak A \subseteq \mathscr
>  P(X)$, using the Hopf's Extension Theorem. Then a set $S$ in $P(X)$ is
> measurable if and only if there exists Borel sets $B^*, B_* \in
>  \mathbb B (\mathfrak A)$ (the $\sigma$-field generated by $\mathfrak
>  A$) such that $B_*\subseteq S\subseteq B^*$ and $\mu (B_*) =\mu(
>  S)=\mu (B^*)$ where $\mu^*$ is the outer measure defined on $\mathscr
>  P (X)$ as in the proof of the Hopf's Extension Theorem.

In case of $[-N, N)$, $\mathfrak A=$ the finite disjoint union of subsets of the form $[a,b)\subseteq [-N,N)$ and the outer measure is defined as usual.

Here's my attempt of the problem:

$(\Leftarrow )$ Suppose that for each $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an
open set $G\supseteq S$ and a closed set $F\subseteq S$ such that $\mu
 (G)-\mu (F)<\varepsilon$. Then for each $n\in \mathbb {N}$ there exists an
open set $G_n\supseteq S$ and a closed set $F_n\subseteq S$ such that $\mu
 (G)-\mu (F)<1/n$. Define $G=\cap_{n\in \mathbb N}G_n$ and $F=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}F_n$. Then $\mu (G)-\mu(F)< \mu (G_n)-\mu (F_n)< 1/n$. Thus, $\mu (G)=\mu (F) = \mu^*(S)$ and also $F\subseteq S \subseteq G$ and $F, G\in\mathbb B (\mathfrak A)$.

$(\Rightarrow )$ Suppose that $S$ is measurable. Then by the Theorem, there exists Borel sets $B^*, B_* \in \mathbb B (\mathfrak A)$ such that $B_*\subseteq S\subseteq B^*$ and $\mu (B_*) =\mu(S)=\mu (B^*)$. Let $\varepsilon >0$. Then there exists $\{ J_i \}_{i\in \mathbb N} \subseteq \mathfrak A$ such that $B^*\subseteq \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N}{J_i}$ and $\sum_{i\in \mathbb N} \mu (J_i)< \mu (B^*)+\varepsilon /2$.

Each $J_i$ is a finite disjoint union of subsets of the form $[a,b)\subseteq [-N,N)$. So suppose $J_i=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{n_i} [a_{i,k},b_{i,k})$. Let $\delta_i =\min \{ a_{i,2}-b_{i,1}, a_{i,3}-b_{i,2}, \ldots, a_{i,n_i} -b_{i,n_i-1}, \frac{\varepsilon}{2^in_i} \}$. Define $U_i=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{n_i} (\delta_k - a_{i, k}, b_{i,k})$. Then $\sum _{k=1}^\infty \mu (U_i) <\mu (B^*)+\epsilon$ and also $S\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} U_i$.

I am not sure to how proceed after this. Any hints will be appreciated!